# Is there any way to share gif on apps like whatsapp?

Tags: android, android-intent, share, gif

whenever i share gif on whatsapp they treat them like bitmap? how ever same thing woking fine while share gif with Gmail? i searched a lot but unable to find any why to share gifs with whatsapp. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is completely in hands of whatsapp. It can treat it in whatever way it desires. So you can not force it t do something else.

Answer (score 0):

The Android version of WhatsApp supports GIF images in the latest version.
Read the changelog.

Tip: Convert your gif to a video without sound and then share it to support older versions of WhatsApp.